# How to make camera take picture when proximity sensor is activated?

Tags: android

**I'm interested in knowing how to activate the camera the i have in my program when the proximity sensor is triggered or activated.** I already made a sensor and a camera button that launches the camera on the phone but I can't find a way to make it so the sensor when triggered it launches the camera and takes the picture. By the way I'm using Android Studio to make this.

**Here is my code from Main Activity:**

```
package com.adalhub.adalhub.sensor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

TextView proxText;
SensorManager sm;
Sensor proxSensor;


private static String logtag = "CameraApp8";
private static int TAKE_PICTURE = -1;
private Uri imageUri;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button cameraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    // calls button of camera, when button is clicked the camera decides to got to cameraListener










    sm= (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    proxSensor=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    proxText= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.proximityTextView);
    // this stuff literaly only makes proximity sensor

    sm.registerListener(this, proxSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    // this is just the type of prox sensor






}









    // when click button this is triggered
private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // makes it go into camera mode
        takePhoto(v);
    }

};



private void takePhoto(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "picture.jpg");
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri selectedImage= imageUri;
        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        try{
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
















@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    proxText.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
    //SET AUTOMATIC PHOTO HERE


}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Camera (or Camera2) API to take a picture without going through the camera app.  As for the sensor-  the value in the array is the distance in cm of the object.  Determine some threshold you're ok with, and take the picture whenever the previous value was greater than that value and the new one is less than it.

Comment: But how would i compare the values of the threshold and the value on the array, as far as for the sensor?

Comment: The distance in the array is whatever is in values[0].  Just do if (values[0] < THRESHOLD && previousValue > THRESHOLD)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want to take photo on change in sensor values then you should create your own camera as using camera intent will require user involvement.

Secondly Android sensors are very **sensitive** (values changes almost every nano second) so taking picture on change in sensor value will be CPU and Disk intensive operation instead you can take picture in intervals like check for change in sensor value after an interval. To do so you may use [Camera V2 API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html). CameraV2 [can take picture repeatedly for indefinite time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#setRepeatingRequest(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler)).

Here is a sample of how to use camera V2 API :-  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Finally if you are trying to detect motion then using proximity sensor might not be a good idea as it have very low range and and capture angle. You can look at this repo for motion detection and using sensors :-

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/android-motion-detection/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/motion_detection/SensorsActivity.java

Detecting motion in Android way :-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html